# Evaluation of the following definite integral

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals, quantum-mechanics

$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin\left(\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}+\frac{k^2}{\sqrt{2}}}\,\,\right)}{\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}+\frac{k^2}{\sqrt{2}}}} \cos(k) \,dk
$$

I arrived at this form of the integral while evaluating the causal propagator corresponding to a second order linear partial differential equation in position and time that resembles the Klein-Gordon equation of relativistic quantum mechanics in form. I'm having difficulty in solving this integral. I tried to do this using integration by parts and I may have to use the concept of branch points (which I'm not quite familiar with). A guidance on how to go about evaluating this further would be appreciated.

Comment: Since your title does not typeset properly, this question is impossible to answer.

Comment: The integrand as currently written is a constant function of the variable of integration.

Comment: Was $dk$ rather than $dx$ intended? $\qquad$

Comment: Yes. Edited now.

Comment: i see no chance to compute this

Comment: I'm fairly certain I saw a generalization of this integral in Gradshteyn and Ryzhik. However, posting the answer from there doesn't really answer the question, does it?

Comment: @teadawg1337, it would absolutely answer this question, at least in part. Why don't you post it as a comment or as a community wiki answer? Knowing the result will be enough in most cases and if not, it will help find the solution

Comment: By the way, Jayanth Jayakumar, are you sure this integral converges?

Comment: Making substitution $$\sinh t=\frac{k}{\sqrt{2\sqrt{2}-2}}$$ and using the fact that the integrand is even, we obtain: $$2 \sqrt[4]{2} \int_0^\infty \sin(a \cosh t) \cos (b \sinh t) dt $$ Here $a=\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}$ and $b=\sqrt{2\sqrt{2}-2}$. If the integral actually converges, I would guess it's somehow connected to [Bessel functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function)

Comment: Mathematica says the latter integral diverges, it doesn't make sense of your original integral at all

Comment: @YuriyS I have posted it as a community wiki answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to submit a partial answer which provides an explicit result. As noted [in the comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2064969/evaluation-of-the-following-definite-integral?noredirect=1#comment4330642_2064969), this integrand is even. After some rearrangements, we obtain 
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sin\left(\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}+\frac{k^2}{\sqrt{2}}}\,\,\right)}{\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}+\frac{k^2}{\sqrt{2}}}}\cos(k)\,dk=2\sqrt[4]{2}\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{2}}\sqrt{2\sqrt{2}-2+k^2}\,\right)}{\sqrt{2\sqrt{2}-2+k^2}}\cos(k)\,dk.$$ 
This latter integral is of a form found in Gradshteyn and Ryzhik, specifically formula $3.876.1$ (Note: I only have access to the Fifth Edition, so I'm unsure of its location in newer editions).

> $$3.876.1\;\;\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin{\left(p\sqrt{x^2+a^2}\right)}}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}\cos(bx)\,dx=\cases{\frac{\pi}2 J_0\left(a\sqrt{p^2-b^2}\right), & \text{if $0<b<p$}\\[2ex] 0, & \text{if $b>p>0$}}$$

In the case of our particular integral, $a=\sqrt{2\sqrt{2}-2}$, $b=1$, and $p=\frac1{\sqrt[4]{2}}$. Since $1>\frac1{\sqrt[4]{2}}>0$, our integral falls under the second category; thus, the result that we seek to prove is the following:

> $$\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{2}}\sqrt{2\sqrt{2}-2+k^2}\,\right)}{\sqrt{2\sqrt{2}-2+k^2}}\cos(k)\,dk\stackrel{?}{=}0.$$